# Pass complex type to AWS API gateway endpoint

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have an aws api gateway endpoint that I am trying to test using [`Mock Lambda Test Tool`](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Tools/LambdaTestTool) command. The aws api gateway endpoint expects a input type which has NoOFHours, AutoRecharge properties. I am passing the body as "body": "{"NoOFHours":51&"\AutoRecharge":false}" but the aws framework throws a "Error deserializing the input JSON to type APIGatewayProxyRequest" error.

How should a complex type be passed to a aws api gateway for testing?

```
 public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> CreatePaymentIntent(APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayProxyRequest, ILambdaContext context)
      {

      }

public class CreatePaymentIntentInput
    {
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public int NoOFHours { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public bool AutoRecharge { get; set; }=false;
      }
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
System.Exception: Error deserializing the input JSON to type APIGatewayProxyRequest
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.BuildParameters(ExecutionRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src142363207\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 214
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ExecutionRequest request) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src142363207\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 52
---------------- Inner 1 Exception ------------
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.Runtime.LambdaExecutor.BuildParameters(ExecutionRequest request, ILambdaContext context) in C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src142363207\src\Tools\LambdaTestTool\src\Amazon.Lambda.TestTool\Runtime\LambdaExecutor.cs:line 202
---------------- Inner 2 Exception ------------
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializerException: Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to type Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.APIGatewayProxyRequest: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: \. Path 'body', line 2, position 24.
   at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)
---------------- Inner 3 Exception ------------
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: \. Path 'body', line 2, position 24.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
   at Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](Stream requestStream)
```

**`Sample Input to test API gateway endpoint:`**

```
{
  "body": "{\"NoOFHours"\:51&"\AutoRecharge"\:false}",
  "resource": "/items/{proxy+}",
  "path": "/payments",
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "isBase64Encoded": true,
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {
    "foo": ["bar"]
  },
  "pathParameters": {
    "proxy": "/payments"
  },
  "stageVariables": {
    "baz": "qux"
  },
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
    "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
    "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
    "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
    "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
    "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
    "Host": "1234567890.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Custom User Agent String",
    "Via": "1.1 08f323deadbeefa7af34d5feb414ce27.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
    "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "cDehVQoZnx43VYQb9j2-nvCh-9z396Uhbp027Y2JvkCPNLmGJHqlaA==",
    "X-Forwarded-For": "127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2",
    "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
  },
  "multiValueHeaders": {
    "Accept": ["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"],
    "Accept-Encoding": ["gzip, deflate, sdch"],
    "Accept-Language": ["en-US,en;q=0.8"],
    "Cache-Control": ["max-age=0"],
    "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": ["https"],
    "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": ["true"],
    "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": ["false"],
    "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": ["false"],
    "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": ["false"],
    "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": ["US"],
    "Host": ["0123456789.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"],
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": ["1"],
    "User-Agent": ["Custom User Agent String"],
    "Via": ["1.1 08f323deadbeefa7af34d5feb414ce27.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"],
    "X-Amz-Cf-Id": ["cDehVQoZnx43VYQb9j2-nvCh-9z396Uhbp027Y2JvkCPNLmGJHqlaA=="],
    "X-Forwarded-For": ["127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2"],
    "X-Forwarded-Port": ["443"],
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": ["https"]
  },
  "requestContext": {
    "accountId": "123456789012",
    "resourceId": "123456",
    "stage": "prod",
    "requestId": "c6af9ac6-7b61-11e6-9a41-93e8deadbeef",
    "requestTime": "09/Apr/2015:12:34:56 +0000",
    "requestTimeEpoch": 1428582896000,
    "identity": {
      "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
      "accountId": null,
      "cognitoIdentityId": null,
      "caller": null,
      "accessKey": null,
      "sourceIp": "127.0.0.1",
      "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
      "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
      "userArn": null,
      "userAgent": "Custom User Agent String",
      "user": null
    },
    "path": "/payments",
    "resourcePath": "/items/{proxy+}",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "apiId": "1234567890",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by changing the `"body"` to `"{'NoOFHours':51,'AutoRecharge':false}"`.